# My Django test is failing due to csrf_token value?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-unittest

**I Think the two csrf value is not same that is why my test case is failing. How do i test the template is working good?**

---

### FAIL: test_home_page_can_save_a_POST_request (lists.tests.HomePageTest)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "G:\dj_proj\ObeyTheTestingGoat\superlists\lists\tests.py", line 46, in te
st_home_page_can_save_a_POST_request

```
    self.assertEqual(response.content.decode(), expect_html)
AssertionError: '<!DO[178 chars]lue="mksJcHsmmhRKsu96jGJaqz7sh593cCLcG8AEkK5CC[2
13 chars]tml>' != '<!DO[178 chars]lue="kGamofdgnvgVD2MfLaIZKrLQ99WOYjzlEuihwiQwD
[213 chars]tml>'
```

---

Ran 4 tests in 0.015s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...

---

```
    def test_home_page_can_save_a_POST_request(self):
        request = HttpRequest()
        request.method = 'POST'
        request.POST['item_text'] = 'A new list item'

        response = views.home_page(request)

        self.assertIn('A new list item', response.content.decode())
        
        expect_html = render_to_string('home.html', context={'new_item_text':'A new list item'}, request=request)
        self.assertEqual(response.content.decode(), expect_html)
```

Comment: show your test class/function

Comment: i have the test case

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes, you can use `Client` class from `django.test` to make request. It is also present as an object in your test class, if you inherit from `TestCase`. This will help you get rid of the `csrf` issue.

```py
from django.test import TestCase

class TestView(TestCase):
     def test_home_page_can_save_a_POST_request(self):
        url = '<url-to-your-view>'
        response = self.client.post((url, data=['item_text'])

        # perform your assertions then
        self.assertIn('A new list item', response.content.decode())
        
        expect_html = render_to_string('home.html', context={'new_item_text':'A new list item'}, request=request)
        self.assertEqual(response.content.decode(), expect_html)
```

You may read the documentation regarding [testing for csrf](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/#testing) and [unit-testing in `django`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/) for more details.

Comment: tryt to set `msxDiff=0` inside your test `class` to see the complete difference, if it is due to the `csrf` value, see you see the relevant documentation links in the answer to figure out your issue in more detail.

Comment: it is showing that value of csrf token is changed. i used assertMultiLineEqual with maxdiff statement.